# Laravel getting data of logged in user from different tables based on foreign keys and id

Tags: laravel-5.4

Hi iam beginner of laravel ,i have four tables users,students,class,section

**users**

- id
- username
- password
- usertype

**Students**

- id
- name
- roll no
- class_id
- section_id

**class**

- id
- class_name

**sections**

- id
- section_name

when i logged in getting user name and getting role no from student tables by using following method

User.php

public function getAttribute($key)

```
{$profile = student::where('stud_adm_id', '=', $this->attributes['username'])->first()->toArray();

    foreach ($profile as $attr => $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($attr, $this->attributes)) {
            $this->attributes[$attr] = $value;
        }
    }

    return parent::getAttribute($key);
}
```

But i want to get class name and section name from related tables also to show logged in user complete profile....

and in view page called values as shown below

```
<h4>ID: &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->roll_no}}</h4>
<h4>Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->name }}</h4>
```

Let me know how to get values of class and section also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships).

Defining relationships in student.php

```
class Student {

    ...

    public function class() {
        $this->belongsTo('App\Class');
    }

    public function section() {
        $this->belongsTo('App\Section');
    }

    ...

}
```

Then you can retrieve the `class` and `section` relationship when you get the `student` model.

```
$student = Student::where('stud_adm_id', $username)->first();
$class = $studnet->class;
$section = $student->section;
```